Meaning of asymptotic in the context of stochastic process
So for a fractional Brownian motion, I define $k^{th}$ variation as
$$ S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{|B_{H}(i\times\frac{T}{n}) - B_{H}((i - 1)\times\frac{T}{n})|^k} $$
where T is fixed and $B_H$ is a standard fractional Brownian motion
I am writing a literature about this and want to be precise with my words as I am slightly confused by some literature about asymptotic properties.
Let's say I have some estimator $\hat{H}$ that relies on $S_n$ through a determinant and reversible function. Literature I read referred to the asymptotic properties (such as distribution) of  $\hat{H}$ with regard to $n$ for a fractional Brownian motion $B_H$.
So I am wondering:
"for a fractional Brownian motion $B_H$ with regard to $n$" - does this mean it considers a specific realisation of the fBm? As I thought asymptotic properties considers the limiting behaviour  of the estimator w.r.p.t sample size and increasing $n$ in this case is more like thinking in the continuous sense?  and in addition, I thought $S_n$ is the random variable and sample size in my understanding is referring to number of fBm paths (as for each path, there is a different value of $S_n$ for the same true $H$)
